How to make Java Vaadin 24 Grid Cell Ready to Edit By Pressing a Key
I'm trying to make my Java Vaadin (V24) grid more easily editable. My goal is to have the cell I navigate to ready to be edited by pressing a key (Key A for example).
The problem is there seems to be no direct command to make a cell ready to be edited at once.
editor.editItem(currentItem.get());

only opens the editor but it is not possible to proceed with editing directly.
I also cannot find a way to save the currently focused item since it must be an Optional which means I cannot use that in further functions that easily.
Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

If I understand correctly, you want to have some kind of key input that will toggle a row to become editable. Here is a demonstration of using the Vaadin Shortcuts API to perform this with the keys 'CTRL' + 'A':
var grid = new Grid<Person>();

// setup column editor components
var binder = new Binder<Person>();
grid.getEditor().setBinder(binder);

var nameEditor = new TextField();
binder.bind(nameEditor, Person::getName, Person::setName);

var ageEditor = new TextField();
binder.bind(ageEditor, Person::getAge, Person::setAge);

// setup the grid
grid.addColumn(Person::getName)
        .setEditorComponent(nameEditor);
grid.addColumn(Person::getAge)
        .setEditorComponent(ageEditor);
grid.addComponentColumn(person -> 
    new Button("Show Bean Value", e -> Notification.show(person.toString())));

// CTRL + A toggles the selected rows editor
Shortcuts.addShortcutListener(this,
                () -> {
                    var editItem = grid.getEditor().getItem();
                    var selectedItem = grid.getSelectedItems().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
                    grid.getEditor().closeEditor();
                    if (editItem != selectedItem) {
                        grid.getEditor().editItem(selectedItem);
                        nameEditor.focus();
                    }
                },
                Key.KEY_A, KeyModifier.CONTROL)
        .listenOn(grid);

// add some dummy data
grid.setItems(
        new Person("Jeff", "20"),
        new Person("Tom", "23")
);


// person pojo class
public static class Person {
   private String name;
   private String age;
   //... getters and setters
}


Some additional notes:

Using a modifier key, such as CTRL, ensures that you don't need to handle stepping on standard input
grid.getEditor().closeEditor() allows you to immediately toggle off editing and write the current editor field value to the bean
grid.addCellFocusListener(...) can be useful if you want to track what specific cell is currently targeted (potentially you could auto-focus the correlating editor component when CTRL + A is entered)

